# Create elements based on checkbox selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML:

```
<fieldset style="" title="Variaciones" id="product-create-step-3" class="fstep">
    <legend>Variaciones</legend>
    <section id="choices">    
        <input type="checkbox" value="24" id="24" name="Size"> Size
        <input type="checkbox" value="25" id="25" name="Color"> Color

        <section style="display: none" class="options_holder"></section>
        <section style="display: none" class="variations_holder"></section></section>
</fieldset>
```

I need to create some `input` based on what checkbox/es was marked. For example if I mark first one 'Size' I should obtain this:

```
<section style="display: none" class="options_holder">
    <input name="size[24][]" value="" placeholder="Write your size" />
</section>
```

if I mark second one 'Color' I should obtain this:

```
<section style="display: none" class="options_holder">
    <input name="color[25][]" value="" placeholder="Write your color" />
</section>
```

if I mark both 'Size' & 'Color' I should obtain this:

```
<section style="display: none" class="options_holder">
    <input name="size[24][]" value="" placeholder="Write your size" />
    <input name="color[25][]" value="" placeholder="Write your color" />
</section>
```

How I would do that?

**UPDATE 1**

I'm trying to get which checkbox was checked by doing this:

```
$("#choices :checked").each(function() {
    console.log(this.id + "was checked");
});
```

But it's not working

**UPDATE 2**

I realize into another problem, how I check when a checkbox was checked and after trigger some code without know any data of the checkbox? I have a code that generates check-boxes on the fly  so I'll never know their name's or id's or any other data. My template for that creation looks like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="{{ entity.getLabel|lower }}" id="{{ entity.getLabel|lower ~ "_choice" }}" value="{{ entity.getId }}" /> {{ entity.getLabel }}
```

Where for example name could take "color" and in that case id will be "color_choice" or name could take "size" and in that case id will be "size_choice", sometimes one is created some time both are created. What I need to know and I don't is how to know which check-box was checked and when trigger some event as for example create some others input's on the fly. How do I deal with this part too?

Comment: It might be easier if, instead of *creating* the fields, you have them there all the time, and hide or show (and enable/disable) as necessary.

Comment: Quite easily - look up the jQuery `append()` method. Listen for the checks and then append the markup as you want it to `$('.options_holder')`

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the suggestion but no, is not since I will allow to add more inputs like the one talked before meaning **Add size**, **Add color**

Comment: @Reynier it would still be easier to just show/hide. what happens when you un-check the checkbox? it has to go away right?

Comment: @RobSchmuecker the problem is not the `append()` I could use also `html()` to replace a piece of content or maybe `after()` or something else, the problem is how to get all the marked checkboxes in order to build elements properly

Comment: listen to the change event...

Comment: @KevinB yes, it should destroy the element but this could be done using `.html()` or I missing?

Comment: @Reynier perhaps look up how to select checked boxed in the jQuery docs.

Comment: @KevinB what you mean with 'listen to the change event'?, anyway I'll take a look at your suggestions and come back with some code in case I have problems

Comment: I was responding to *"the problem is how to get all the marked checkboxes in order to build elements properly"* You don't need to get them all. Just listen to the change event on each one individually since each one is associated to it's own additional input.

Comment: I think the selector should be `$("#choices input:checked")`, not `$("#choices :checked")`, as the pseudo selector is tied to the input element, not the element with the #choices id.

Comment: @KevinB can you take a look at the editions I made to main post and give me some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, your javascript should work if you change your selector to include the element that uses the pseudo-selector:

```
$("#choices input:checked").each(function() {
    console.log(this.id + "was checked");
});
```

As for accessing the attribute values, you can use either the native javascript object that you're using, i.e.:

```
 console.log("value is " + this.value);
```

Or you can use jQuery's [attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/)

```
 console.log("name is " + $(this).attr('name'))
```

A working example showing both cases, as well as having attached the event to any click of input items is at this jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k3B73/

Answer (score 0):

```
<fieldset style="" title="Variaciones" id="product-create-step-3" class="fstep">
    <legend>Variaciones</legend>
    <section>    
        <input type="checkbox" value="24" id="24" name="Size" id='size_choice'> Size
        <input type="checkbox" value="25" id="25" name="Color" id='color_choice'> Color

        <section style="display: none" class="options_holder" id='options_holder'></section>   
        <section style="display: none" class="variations_holder"></section>
    </section>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#size_choice').click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                $("#options_holder").append('<input name="size[24][]" value="" placeholder="Write your size" id="size" />');
            else
                $("#size").destroy();
        });

        $('#color_choice').click(function(){
            if ($(this).is(':checked'))
                $("#options_holder").append('<input name="color[25][]" value="" placeholder="Write your color" id="choice" />');
            else
                $("#color").destroy();
        });
    })
</script>
```